# Excel: How do I reference a date when using SUM IF for multiple columns and date rows

Tags: excel, sumifs

I've tweak this a few times. It seems to be my issue is in the IF Function when I reference a date it does not pick it up.  Do I need to use a specific function for calling a date?  If I change my date to something random, like DAN, the formula works fine.

Example Data table:

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZlsn.png)

What I want it summarized as:

[Summary Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYYpD.png)

Here's what formula i'm trying to use:
=SUM(IF(C2:H2="California",IF(B3:B14="01/01/2018",C3:H14)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula actually works just fine, provided you enter it as array formula (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

[image]

I modified it slightly only so it doesn't take 'hard coded' values and with some careful range locking, this is the final one:

```
=SUM(IF($C$2:$H$2=C$16,IF($B$3:$B$14=$B17,$C3:$H3)))
```

---

Then again, I'd usually go for SUMPRODUCT which feels more natural to me now:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$H$14*($B$3:$B$14=$B17)*($C$2:$H$2=C$16))
            <--  1 --> <------ 2 ------> <-----  3 ----->
```

Where 1 is the full range, 2 is the first condition and 3 is the second condition.

Comment: Sure enough it's working now.  I'm glad I don't have to hard code the values. Yes, I saw the Sumproduct as a possible solution. I'll use these going forward.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the date inside the `DATEVALUE()` function.